# In Silverlight, How to bind SelectedItem of ComboBox in a ControlTemplate to a ViewModel Property

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, controltemplate, selecteditem

I have this code of a `ComboBox` that works and binds the `SelectedItem` to a property in my `ViewModel`:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="luTeacher"
    Margin="0,5,0,0"
    AutoComplete="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ddsTeachers.Data}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeacher, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ValueMember="UserId"
    DisplayMember="FullName"/>
```

But when I try and copy it and use it on a `Combobox` in a `ControlTemplate` it doesn't work:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Margin="0,0,0,4"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="150"
    AutoComplete="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ddsViewTeacher.Data, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNewTeacher,
                           Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
    DisplayMember="FullName"
    ValueMember="UserId"/>
```

The `ItemsSource` works, but the `SelectedItem` does not update. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: I found the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Tell everyone by _answering_ your own question. Otherwise people will see the "unanswered" status of your question and will read it for nothing.